# Edit continuous view sliding windows in pipelinedb

Tags: pipelinedb

I create a continuous view and fill it with my streams.

Now I want to change my old sliding window or change this name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create regular views on top of existing continuous views that further aggregate the rows in continuous views, but you cannot get more granularity than you have defined in your existing continuous views - it's a one way street.

See our [docs on sliding windows](http://docs.pipelinedb.com/sliding-windows.html) for more detail on windowing with PipelienDB or find our dev team in our [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/pipelinedb/pipelinedb) for technical questions.